# Computing Tensor products of modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

I need to calculate some tensor products and stuck the whole night at this simple things. But finally, I confused myself.

When I have a commutative ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ and considering the enveloping algebra of it $R^e=R \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} R^{op}$, then $R^e \cong R^2$ since $R$ is commutative. A $R$-bimodul $M$, is a left $R^e$-module. This means that esspecially $M=R$ is a left $R^e$-module. So in order we have $R^e \otimes_{R^e} M \cong M$. I hope it is correct unit here.
This, in turn, implies that

$(R^e)^m \otimes_{R^e} R \cong R^{2m} \otimes_{R^2} R \cong R^{m+1}$.

But what is about
$\Lambda^2((R^e)^m) \otimes_{R^e} R$ ?

Comment: I'm suspect of the claim $R^e\cong R^2$, $\dim R^e=\dim R\cdot \dim R$ whereas $\dim R^2=2\dim R$.

Comment: I think what you want is that  $R^e \cong R \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} R$.

Comment: I think you cannot deal with a dimension argument here because polynomial rings have not a finite number of basis elements (over $\mathbb{C}$). On the other hand it is easy to see that $R^e \cong \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n]$ and this is basically $R^2$.